# i use daterangepicker in which i want to default select date is before 18 yrs

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

```
    $(function() {
        $("#dob").daterangepicker({
            singleDatePicker: true,
            showDropdowns: true,
            locale: {
                format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
            }     
        });

       $('#dob').daterangepicker({
            endDate: '-6576d' 

        });

    });
```

it is generating two date starting and ending but i want only single calender which displays before 18 yrs date and only choose greater then 18 yrs

Comment: Please do **not** add tags that do not apply to your question

Answer (score 0):

[Single Date Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)

The Date Range Picker can be turned into a single date picker widget with only one calendar.
 In this example, dropdowns to select a month and year have also been enabled at the top of 
 the calendar to quickly jump to different months.

```
    <input type="text" name="birthdate" value="10/24/1950" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('input[name="birthdate"]').daterangepicker({
            singleDatePicker: true,
            showDropdowns: true,
             "startDate": "03/01/2017",
             "endDate": "03/07/2017",
             "minDate": "03/01/2017",
             "maxDate": "03/30/2017"
        }, 
        function(start, end, label) {
            var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
            alert("You are " + years + " years old.");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: no actually it shows your age but i want that person select the age only if he she  is 18 yr old it means end date is -6576 days from today

Comment: use `minDate` and  `maxDate`  to give daterange. see I have edit answer